# Script in Photoshop CS6 that can copy frame number and cursor coordinates into clipboard?

Tags: photoshop, flash-cs6

It is possible to open videos with Photoshop, I use this functionnality in order to measure the speed of an animation on my screen after recording it with OBS.

Is it possible to write a script that, when you click on the picture, saves the **milliseconds of the frame** (or at least the frame number) and the **coordinates** of the click in the clipboard or in a file ?

[image: http://s2.postimg.org/kkuytdxl5/photoshop.jpg]